# Matplotlib markers disappear when edgecolor = 'none'

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.7, markers

I'm trying to make a scatter plot of some PCA data.  I do some pretty typical code:

```
plt.plot(pca[:,0], pca[:,1], '.',ms=3,  markerfacecolor = self.colors[k],
            markeredgecolor = 'none')
```

I want it to show just the marker face color with no outline.  The problem is that the markers disappear completely when markeredgecolor = 'none'.  When I set markerfacecolor='none' or to a color and remove markeredgecolor, it works like expected.

I just updated matplotlib, numpy, etc. to the newest versions, running on Python 2.7.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might try setting the `markersize` to a larger value. `markersize` can be a kwarg to `plot()`, or you can abbreviate as `ms`. e.g.: `..., markersize=20, ...`

Comment: For those trying to do this with `matplotlib.errorbar` using the `markeredgecolor=None` recommended below did not remove the black outlining the symbol.  Instead `markeredgecolor='none'`did work (the symbols were not invisible).  Not surprisingly, it seems the bug that led to this question has been fixed in the past 3 years.

Answer (score 20):

I think this is a bug that was fixed a few months ago: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/598

Regardless of how large you make the markers or if you use `marker='o'` instead of `'.'`, they'll be invisible if you use `markeredgecolor='none'`.

As a workaround, you can just set the edge colors to the same as the face colors.

Answer (score 7):

In matplotlib 1.1

```
>> plt.plot(pca[:,0], pca[:,1], '.', ms=3, markerfacecolor=self.colors[k],
...          markeredgecolor=None)
```

works (note the `None` instead of 'none' for markeredgecolor).

Setting `markeredgewidth=0.0` or `markeredgecolor=self.colors[k]` (as suggested by Joe Kington) should work, too.

Comment: What do you mean by `self.colors[k]`? When I run the similar code it says `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Comment: It is taken from the question. Seems like the the OP is using this command from within a class, which has a colors attribute (which is a dictionary). You can replace it by any matplotlib color (e.g. a string like 'green') if you just want to use the code line to plot something.

Comment: As of now (newer matplotlib), should use `markedgecolor="None"`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596637/10039621).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
x = np.array(np.random.rand(10))
y = np.array(np.random.rand(10))
c = np.arange(len(x))
plt.scatter(x,y, c=c, s=500, cmap = plt.cm.Paired, alpha = 0.5,linewidths=0)
```

Or, this is a good option too:

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=c, s=500, cmap = plt.cm.Paired, alpha = 0.5,edgecolor='face')
```