# Plotting with a transparent marker but non-transparent edge

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, transparency

I'm trying to make a plot in matplotlib with transparent markers which have a fixed color edge . However, I can't seem to achieve a marker with transparent fill.

I have a minimum working example here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y1 = 2*x + 1
y2 = 3*x - 5

plt.plot(x,y1, 'o-', lw=6, ms=14)
plt.plot(x,y2, 'o', ms=14, markerfacecolor=None, alpha=0.5, markeredgecolor='red', markeredgewidth=5)

plt.show()
```

I tried two techniques I found online to achieve this:
1) Setting alpha parameter. However, this makes the marker edge transparent too, which is not the desired effect.
2) Setting markerfacecolor=None, although this has no effect on my plot

Is there a solution to this please?

Comment: Using a scatter plot like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253306/4124317) may be an option.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is tricky in Matplotlib... you have to use a string `"None"` instead of the value `None`, then you can just do:

```
plt.plot(x,y2, 'o', ms=14, markerfacecolor="None",
         markeredgecolor='red', markeredgewidth=5)
```

Comment: As a side note, there is a very good reason for the difference between `None` and `'None'`.  The first means 'do the default thing', the later means "I don't want a color".

Comment: I was just wondering why the simple `None` was not doing what I wanted (empty marker). It is a bit confusing though.

Comment: @Gabriel this is common. In Matplotlib `None` means default while `"None"` means that no color should be used

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question: The result does not have "a marker with transparent fill" (i.e. with an alpha), it is not filled at all. Adding a second plot for the transparent markers is not a solution either, because the color cycle can no longer be used (easily).

Comment: @bluenote the OP  wanted to keep the edges solid while the fill transparent... This was the way I could figure out how to get it done. If you need not full transparency then the second plot would do the trick with the drawbacks you mentioned

Comment: it appears that also specifying the 'alpha' breaks this solution...by providing it, I was getting black fill. removing it, I got no fill

Comment: The alpha breaking does not appear to be a problem in the current matplotlib version (3.0.2, here). Adding `alpha = 0.5` to this solution behaves as expected

Comment: When using certain other plotting functions like `ax.voxels` I'm getting the black fill bug on matplotlib version 3.0.3

Answer (score 8):

In general it seems to be a better solution to use transparent colors, instead of the `alpha` parameter. First of all because it does not affect any other colors and it helps to avoid the black fill bug reported by some in the comments. In this example - using the `voxels` function to draw 2 voxels on the plot - the 4th number in the tuples stored in `colors` represents the alpha value of an RGBA color. These normalized RGBA tuple notations can be used as colors throughout matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
voxels = np.array([[[True],[True]]])
colors = np.array([[[(0., 0., 0., 0.)],[(1.0, 0., 0., 0.5)]]])
ax.voxels(voxels, facecolors=colors, edgecolor='k', linewidth=.5)
plt.show(block=True)
```

[image]