# Pandas GroupBy Scatter Plot - How to plot Open/Hollow Circles

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter

I created a scatter plot of some data from a grouped Pandas Dataframe (see code below). I can't figure out how to set the marker type to an open/unfilled circle. None of the parameters I have found in other posts work (`ms`, `markeredgewidth`, `markerfacecolor`, `facecolor`, `edgewidth` - all listed as "unknown properties").  Is there a parameter I am missing? I am using matplotlib and seaborn.

```
for key, group in grouped_by_model:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='CURR MILEAGE', y='REPAIR TOTAL', color=colors[key], marker = 'o', s=20)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250916/matplotlib-scatter-edge-without-specifying-edgecolor) does not have any upvotes on its answer, so we cannot close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250916/matplotlib-scatter-edge-without-specifying-edgecolor)'s answer, you may use a hollow marker

```
marker=ur"$\u25EF$"
```

to plot the scatter.

```
for key, group in grouped_by_model:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='CURR MILEAGE', y='REPAIR TOTAL', 
                      color=colors[key], marker = ur"$\u25EF$", s=20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This doesn't seem to work though - gave me a SyntaxError - is there a package I need to import?

Comment: No, but without the actual error and the code that produces the error, it's not possible to help. This is also the reason you should always create [mcve]s.

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the lack of helpful sample code.

I figured it out - I had to remove the "ur" like so `marker = "$\u25ef$"`

Comment: That's interesting. For me it only works if the string is a unicode raw string, i.e. with `ur` in front of it.