# Re: Add colorbar to scatterplot with non-filled circles

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I know this question has been asked and answered twice before, but those solutions are >4 yrs old now, and don't work for me at least. When I try out the this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.random(size=(100,))
y = np.random.random(size=(100,))
c = np.random.random(size=(100,))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = ax.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o',c = c)
g.set_facecolor('none')
fig.colorbar(g)
```

I get an empty plot like:

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone else encountered this, and maybe found a solution?
I'm using matplotlib 3.5.1.

Comment: This code works for me with `numpy` version 1.22.2 and `matplotlib` version 3.2.2 ... maybe roll back the matplotlib version to a previous one if nothing else works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, but by using a non-filled marker you should get what you want:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(size=(100,))
y = np.random.random(size=(100,))
c = np.random.random(size=(100,))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = ax.scatter(x, y, marker="$\u25EF$", c=c, s=100)
fig.colorbar(g)
```

[image]

For further details, [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250916/matplotlib-scatter-edge-without-specifying-edgecolor).