# unfilled circles in a data scatter plot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data and I'm doing scatter plot. I want my points to be in empty circles and I'm using facecolor and edgecolor. surprisingly when I define colors for face and edge the codes works, but when I put 'non' as facecolor to have unfilled circles it doesn't accept it, how can I correct it,  here is my code:

```
x,y,dy = np.loadtxt('PKS 0528134 .txt', usecols=[0,2,3], unpack= True)
plt.scatter(10**x, 10**y, marker= 'o', facecolor= 'b', edgecolor= 'r')

plt.xlabel(r'$\nu$', fontsize= 15)
plt.ylabel(r'Log $\nu$ L($\nu$)', fontsize= 15)
plt.xlim(1e12,1e24)
plt.ylim(1e41,1e49)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried `facecolor="None"` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596575/plotting-with-a-transparent-marker-but-non-transparent-edge?

Comment: If you really use `"non"` then that will give an error. You need `"none"` for the facecolor

Comment: I use facecolor= 'non', and it gives me the error "Invalid RGBA argument: 'n'

Comment: Well, you need `facecolor = "none"` instead as shown in the dupe

Comment: gives me the same error

Comment: yes , yes , it works, thanksss alot