# Attempting to plot invisible node in networkx, but getting black node

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to plot a completely invisible node in networkx.  Basically it should be as if it weren't plotted.  However, because of the structure of my code, I can't easily not plot it.  It would be simpler if I could set the `node_color` to be something like `"Invisible"`.

Since networkx uses `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` to plot the nodes, I thought I would approach it like matplotlib.  To do this there, just set the `c` argument for a particular marker to be the string `"None"` (see [Plotting with a transparent marker but non-transparent edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596575/plotting-with-a-transparent-marker-but-non-transparent-edge?lq=1)).

Here's an example where 2 of the 5 markers are invisible:

```
plt.scatter(range(5), range(5), c = ["None", "black", 'red', "None", 'blue'])
```

[image]

Let's try that with networkx:

```
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100,0.03) 
nodelist = list(G.nodes())   
colorlist = ["None" if node%2==0 else "red" for node in nodelist] #even nodes should be invisible
nx.draw_networkx(G, nodelist=nodelist, node_color=colorlist)
```

[image]

Notice that the even nodes are not invisible, they are black.

I don't understand, because when I look at the [source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes) from networkx, the relevant line appears to be

```
node_collection = ax.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1],
                             s=node_size,
                             c=node_color,
                             marker=node_shape,
                             cmap=cmap,
                             vmin=vmin,
                             vmax=vmax,
                             alpha=alpha,
                             linewidths=linewidths,
                             edgecolors=edgecolors,
                             label=label)
```

so `colorlist` should be sent directly to `scatter` without any alteration.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?  Why are these nodes turning up black?

Comment: Just to be clear to potential answerers - my question is "why are the nodes turning up black?"  I know the standard networkx ways to only plot a subset of the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some time to find the issue, but I was able to reproduce `networkx` behaviour with `matplotlib`:

```
pl.scatter(range(5), range(5), c = ["None", "black", 'red', "None", 'blue'], alpha=1.0)
```

`Networkx` default parameter `alpha=1.0` (which is different from `alpha=None` of `matplotlib`). 
The following worked for me:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, nodelist=nodelist, node_color=colorlist, alpha=None, with_labels=False)
```

Thanks to the comment of @Paul Brodersen: It looks like the different default values were resolved: Compare code of [2.3](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes) vs. [latest](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes) (2.4.xy).

Comment: As of May 19, the default value for the alpha parameter in networkx is None, but then @Joel may not be running the latest version of networkx. Upvoted regardless.

Comment: The version of my test environment was 2.2. Just checked the code in 2.3 its still 1.0 and in the latest it's now None. Added this.

Comment: Great - thanks to all.  I was running 2.1.  I may upgrade then.